# bash: bower: command not found, I have no idea what to do

Tags: node.js, git, bash, bower

Sorry to be the 1 million person creating a similar topic but I really read trough all the others and they didn't help me at all. I've tried setting the "path" correctly by doing: set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\ "Your username" \AppData\Roaming\npm. Regardless of my effort, it still doesn't work. I've tried reinstalling it and even reinstalling GIT on my main drive just to see if there will be a difference with the path but still zero. Here, I've pasted the output from my GIT prompt. If anyone has any ideas how to fix it, I'm open to suggestions.

```
$ npm install -g bower
D:\Programs\GIT\Git\usr\local\bower -> D:\Programs\GIT\Git\usr\local\node_mods\bower\bin\bower
bower@1.7.9 D:\Programs\GIT\Git\usr\local\node_modules\bower

Kosio@User MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Web Projects/RESTful API/bookstore/client
$ which bower
which: no bower in (/c/Users/Kosio/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/Kosio/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corpoion/PhysX/Common:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Program Files (x86)/Il/iCLS Client:/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDO/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Prograiles/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program Files/Intel/Il(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Mgement Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Managementgine Components/IPT:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/OpenCL SDK/2.0/bin/x86:/c/Pram Files (x86)/Intel/OpenCL SDK/2.0/bin/x64:/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows LiShared:/c/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Gtarp/2.12/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone:/c/WINDOWS/system32/config/symprofile/.dnx/bin:/c/Program Files/Microsoft DNX/Dnvm:/d/Programs/Node JS:/cmc/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/3.2/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_per
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're using Git Bash. This command won't work for setting `PATH`:

```
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\ "Your username" \AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Try to write like this:

```
PATH="$PATH:/c/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/npm"
```

Or this might work too, but I cannot test it now:

```
PATH="$PATH:"'C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm'
```

Also you're `PATH` is very long. I suggest to use a custom `PATH`, containing only the paths necessarily for Node.js development to reduce the noise and unexpected behavior.